# iOS grayscale/black & white

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics

I am having an issue with some code that changes a UIImage to grayscale. It works right on iPhone/iPod, but on iPad whatever is already drawn gets all stretched and skewed in the process.

It also sometimes crashes only on iPad on the line
imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);

Here is the code:

```
CGContextRef ctx;
CGImageRef imageRef = [self.drawImage.image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

int byteIndex = 0;
int grayScale;

for(int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
{
    grayScale = (rawData[byteIndex] + rawData[byteIndex + 1] + rawData[byteIndex + 2]) / 3;

    rawData[byteIndex] = (char)grayScale;
    rawData[byteIndex+1] = (char)grayScale;
    rawData[byteIndex+2] = (char)grayScale;
    //rawData[byteIndex+3] = 255;

    byteIndex += 4;
}


ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                            8,
                            CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                            CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast ); 

imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

CGContextRelease(ctx);  

self.drawImage.image = rawImage;  

free(rawData);
```

Comment: What happens if you use the same image you are using on the iPhone on the iPad? I suspect there are differences in the image format or something. Also, note that there is a better algorithm to convert to gray scale which is add together 30% of the red value, 59% of the green value, and 11% of the blue value like so: grayScale = ((rawData[byteIndex] * 0.3f) + (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 0.59) + (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 0.11));

Comment: The image format is the same each time. You are able to draw as you please, and then are able to hit the grayscale button. It just skews on the iPad and often crashes on     imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);     only on iPad

Answer (score 2):

Consider leveraging the [CIColorMonochrome](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter%E2%80%A6) filter available in iOS 6.

```
void ToMonochrome()
{
    var mono = new CIColorMonochrome();
    mono.Color = CIColor.FromRgb(1, 1, 1);
    mono.Intensity = 1.0f;
    var uiImage = new UIImage("Images/photo.jpg");
    mono.Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(uiImage.CGImage);
    DisplayFilterOutput(mono, ImageView);
}

static void DisplayFilterOutput(CIFilter filter, UIImageView imageView)
{
    CIImage output = filter.OutputImage;
    if (output == null)
        return;
    var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
    var renderedImage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
    var finalImage = new UIImage(renderedImage);
    imageView.Image = finalImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with some help elsewhere

Got rid of an extra context being used and changed the bitmap format

```
CGContextRef ctx;
CGImageRef imageRef = [self.drawImage.image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);

ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                            width,
                            height,
                            bitsPerComponent,
                            bytesPerRow,
                            colorSpace,
                            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host); 

CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

int byteIndex = 0;
int grayScale;

for(int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
{
    grayScale = (rawData[byteIndex] + rawData[byteIndex + 1] + rawData[byteIndex + 2]) / 3;

    rawData[byteIndex] = (char)grayScale;
    rawData[byteIndex+1] = (char)grayScale;
    rawData[byteIndex+2] = (char)grayScale;
    //rawData[byteIndex+3] = 255;

    byteIndex += 4;
}


imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(ctx);  

self.drawImage.image = rawImage;  

free(rawData);
```